# javascript regular expressions with variable content

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

I have a working reg expression that does a replace function based on the expression. It works perfect. It finds a specific string based on the  beginning of the string and the expression. This is it:

```
str.replace(/\bevent[0-9]*\=/, "event");
```

what this does is it changes `event=1` to `event`.

What if `event` was a variable word? What if I needed to look for `conference` also?

I have tried:

```
var type = "conference";

str.replace(/\b/ + type+ /[0-9]*\=/, "conference");
```

and:

```
str.replace(/\b/type/[0-9]*\=/, "conference");
```

neither worked.

how can I pass a javascript string into a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the `RegExp` Object:

```
str.replace(RegExp('\b' + reStr + '[0-9]*\='),StrToReplaceWith)
```

Comment: I took your answer because it fit exactly what I was looking for. Is it strange that the '\b' would not work? I had to take it out.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have much experience with the word boundary character =(

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing a RegEx literal, use a string to create a new [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\b' + var + '[0-9]'), …)
```

Comment: I guess its kind of messed up that I can only pick one answer, but your answer worked perfectly. I did have to take out the '\b' though. That didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new regex object with your variable.

read this...

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Ok. This still answers his question.